# SQL Server database access issue from AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sequelize.js

I'm getting this error while accessing SQL Server database from aws-lambda. Everything works fine from local machine.Only having access issue when executing the code from lambda.

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 10.2.3.44\SQLSRVR  code: ETIMEOUT

This is my code snippet, any help would be appreciated!

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('DBname', null, null, {
  dialect: 'mssql',
  host: '10.2.3.44',   //MSSQL Server IP sample
  dialectOptions: {
    authentication: {
      type: 'ntlm',
      options: {
        domain: 'addidas',
        userName: "uname",
        password: "pwd"
      }
    },
    options: {
      instanceName: 'SQLSRVR'
    }
  }
})
async function connect() {
    try {
      await sequelize.authenticate();
      console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
    }
  }
connect();
```

Comment: Does your Lambda function have internet access if that database is outside of AWS?

Comment: Where is you ql server located? Do you have any firewall rules that allow your local machine but not other clients? For instance on azure you have to explicitly allow any IP address that is not within azure to be able to access the sql server.

Comment: Please Edit your question to provide more details. For example, where is the SQL Server hosted? Is it an Amazon RDS database?

Comment: You probably need this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html

Comment: `10.2.3.44` is  private address. Nothing on the internet knows how to get to it unless you do some kind of port forwarding from a public internet address.

Comment: No VPC setup for lambda, so yes lamba should be able to access. DB engineers has confirmed no access restiction for this when using this particular user(I will double check this with them once again because I'm also suspecting it could be because of the SQL network restriction rules!). It is not in Amazon RDS, instead on another onpremise machine which is exposed to internet.

Comment: You need to talk to your network engineers not your db enginners `10.2.3.44` is used simultaneously by zillions of hosts right now. Which one do you want to connect to? It's a private address. You need a public address to connect to, not a private address. _Unless_ you have an AWS hybrid network set up

Comment: Thanks, I will deep dive into this and get back!

Answer (score 1):

It was because of the network restrictions only, as assumed. So had to assign lambdas in the same network which SQL server is hosted.
Thanks for all the suggestions.